# Making copies with library projects effectively

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app made, I want to convert this into a `library project`. After that i want to make its copies for different company logos and details.

The major changes that I need to do is, change drawable resources, and change Constants.java file.

Instead of copying whole code , I want to convert this code into library and use it to make different copies. The problem is, once i convert it into library, How can i link my Constants.java in it and how can i link my `drawable resources` to the xml files in library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try by myself yesterday.For example, If your library project call R.drawable.logo it will looking for drawable logo on your main project firstly if your project don't have R.drawable.logo the system will looking on your library project.

so the resource in library project is a default. If you want to change logo or some resource just use the same name in your main project.

Answer (score 0):

It may be achieved with Ant. Google for further instructions. 
  P.S.: I'm not 100% sure, but, as I know, in eclipse you may only "copying whole code".